# ReactJS: move the positioning of <div/>?

Tags: javascript

I have a But, once I place the `<Link/>` wrapper, it slightly repositions the `<div/>`

Why does it do so and how can I get it not to?

```
       <Link to="Home" style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>

      </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the resulant html?

From your description it sounds like it is:

```
<Link to="Home" style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
    <div></div>
    <div>I'm clickable</div>
    <div>And so am I</div>
    <img src='clickable.jpg' />
</Link>
```

Are there any parents anchors/Link elements?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by resultant? Yes, the parent has the following css:   `margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;`